# Angular date-picker select end of a year

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

My goal is to make the angular date-picker pick the end of a the selected year and present the 31.12th of this year.
I´m using moment.js.

My code:

```
scope.ngModel = moment(scope.ngModel).endOf('year');
```

In my controller it´s:

```
2013-10-28T10:00:00.000Z
```

for the time.
When I load the page, it´s `"2013-12-31T22:59:59.999Z"` -> Perfect!!
But when I´m selecting another year via the date-picker, e.g. 2002, it´s:

```
"2002-01-01T11:59:59.000Z"
```

and there´s always the 01.01. of the year.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Without any refactoring just `moment().subtract(1, 'day')` one day each time problem occurs or simply after manual picking :D!